# QGraphicsView framework performance issue for large number of items

Tags: qt, qt5

I am using qt 5.0.1 in windows. I am creating 200k+ custom QGraphicsItem. I have added basic functionalists in these custom items, like mouse hover, mouse click etc.. This items are static. But on top of these items I add some items (200 max) which animates (different property animation, scale, opacity etc).
When I add those items in the scene it become extremely slow, in a relatively powerful workstation.

```
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, width, height);
scene->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::darkGray);
scene->setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene::NoIndex);

QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView( scene );
view->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, false);
view->setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorViewCenter);
view->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
view->resize( width, height );
view->setOptimizationFlags(QGraphicsView::DontSavePainterState);
view->setViewportUpdateMode( QGraphicsView::SmartViewportUpdate);
view->setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);
view->setCacheMode(QGraphicsView::CacheBackground);
view->setViewportUpdateMode( QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);
view->show();
```

I have tried the following, but it makes the rendered view extremely bad, as it seems to enable antialiasing, but I need some pixel label precision.

```
view->setViewport(new QGLWidget( QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers)));
```

Am I missing some important Qt programming tricks? Please suggest. I can post the code, or explain more if in case please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there anyway to reduce the QPropertyAnimation frame rate? May be this will help?

Comment: How many items are visible at any one time?  Try setting the viewport update to `QGraphicsView::MinimalViewportUpdate` or `QGraphicsView::SmartViewportUpdate`.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a lot of items, the bottleneck is when you have them many on the screen at the same time, which would mean they are fairly small. In such cases, it is advisable to resort to using different LOD - that's level of details. When the item is small, draw a simplified version of it. Combine that with LOD baking and caching and an OpenGL widget to draw onto and you could easily get tens or even hundreds of thousands items at a time.